# Rails: Automatically Create & Provision SSL Certificate via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ssl

I'm building a Rails-based website builder as an experiment and am wondering if there's an API for purchasing and provisioning an SSL certificate automatically for a new website via an API. I believe I have a way to set up the domain and unique IP (although still working through that), but not seeing a great way to set up the SSL certificate.

I found some sort of SSL API -- anyone used it? http://doc.rpc.gandi.net/cert/usage.html